# How to disable audio tone on click of any button in my android application?

Tags: java, audio, android

I have custom android application. In which when i click on any button of that application it gives some audio tone(i think it comes from audio Finger). I want to disable it just for my application.

so how can i disable audio tone on button of my android application?

Comment: Have You tried android:soundEffectsEnabled="false" http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:soundEffectsEnabled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with this code:

```
YOUR_BUTTON.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
```

OR

Also you can give property with xml:

```
android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
```

Reference site: [Android View Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSoundEffectsEnabled%28boolean%29)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: do i need to add it for every button or just add it in beginning of xml and it will work for all button in that activity?

Comment: You need to give every button according to your requirement.